# Are there other equalities of the form $\int_{0}^{1}((1+x\sqrt5)/2)^{-3}\mathrm dx=\phi$?

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1+x\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{-3} \mathrm dx=\phi$$

I just write it down in case those don't know what is $\phi$.

$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$

Are there any other integrals of this form such that the value can be expressed in terms of $\phi$?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1+x\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{n}dx=f(\phi)$$

Comment: for any real value $y$, there are many many functions $f$ such that $f(\phi) = y$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you can use the binomial theorem for this, yes?

Comment: It's easy to evaluate this using the obvious $u$-substitution. For any rational number $n \neq -1$, we can see quickly that this can be written as some algebraic expression in $\phi$. (If fact for integers $n \neq 1$ it can be written in the form $a + b \sqrt{5}$.)